# Why I can still access modem GUI when it is bridged?

Tags: networking, router, modem, bridge

I am talking about ISP Modem that means it is a modem/router/switch combo. When I am not bridging I understand the diagram as such,

[image]

The router receive the ISP IP address and route to internal network `192.168.1.0/24`. In this case HostA can easily access router GUI via `192.168.1.1`.

I can't picture what happened during the bridged mode and how HostA can still access 192.168.1.1?

[image]

I understand that when bridging, it behaves simply like a tunnel so the ip address should "flow" through the port right? Please help me picture the basic network topology of modem/router/switch combo under bridged mode.

Comment: The GUI does not just provide settings, but also access to diagnostic data, let alone that the service provider requires this access to get the modem out of bridged mode. Just because you don't see any relative settings doesn't mean there aren't any. A modem/router in bridged mode disables the router part, not the modem part.

Answer (score 1):

Your first graphic properly depicts the modem in **bridged mode.** The second graphic does not correctly depict bridged mode. It's actually not a valid network scenario since a device cannot have the same IP address assigned to multiple interfaces.

When your ISP modem is not bridged it acts like a router (i.e. an [OSI layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer?wprov=sfla1) device). The public IP address associated with your Internet connection is assigned to the modem's WAN interface. Further, its LAN interface will likely have a private IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.1). This means that if you connect your own router to the modem, its WAN interface misty be assigned an IP address on the same subnetwork as the modem's LAN interface, for example 192.168.1.**2**. Then your router's LAN interface would need to be configured to use a *different* subnetwork for its LAN interface, e.g. 192.168.**10**.1

When your ISP modem is bridged it stops acting as a Layer 3 device and instead simply forward all of the [frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer?wprov=sfla1) it receives between your router and the ISP's network*. As a result it doesn't have *any* IP address associated with it and you **must** use your own router (using your own router is optional if using the modem in non-bridged/router mode). The public IP address for your Internet connection is then assigned to the WAN interface of your router and you're free to use whatever IP address for its LAN interface.

> I can't picture what happened during the bridged mode and how HostA can still access 192.168.1.1?

You don't say which device's configuration page you reach when you connect to 192.168.1.1, but I'm guessing it's your router's. If so that's actually expected behavior as explained by the above description of bridged mode.

---

*Even in bridged mode the modem will respond to a connection attempt to the management IP address configured on its LAN interface. This is necessary so you can still access it to change its configuration.

Comment: Thank you this is really clear. Though I have to ask, when under bridged mode. I can still access the modem GUI via 192.168.1.1 provided I statically configured my NIC on computer to be in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. Can you explain how is this possible? It doesn't make sense this way. How can I reach the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet when modem is bridged? I cant draw out the topology

Comment: `You don't say which device's configuration page you reach when you connect to 192.168.1.1` Sorry I am accessing the ISP modem/router/switch combo device

Comment: @Zanko see my edit...does that explain it? Please also edit your question to indicate which device you're accessing when you connect to 192.168.1.1.

Comment: That's normal because even in bridged mode you need a way to access the modem to configure it.

Comment: Im glad it is this way. However, I am just trying to understand how is it possible in term of simple network topology diagram. Can we somehow draw it out using primitive component like modem, router and switch?

Comment: What IP address is assigned to your router's LAN interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77883/discussion-between-zanko-and-twisty-impersonator).

Answer (score 0):

A switch don't know IP addresses, only MAC addresses of devices (as e. g. `cd:b8:a2:35:4f:cc`).

Modern switches "learn" addresses by requested IP addresses (by first trying to send requests to all connected devices and learn, which of them rejected them).

So `198.168.1.1` is for your switch a (relatively) fixed address (e. g. `a5:11:2f:3d:fe:8c`) and it sends frames to it (= to the router) without problems.